# CSS inline-block issue - element being pushed down

Tags: css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q4uNj/
So here's the problem: I can't figure out why the second div - `class="other"` - is being pushed down.

Comment: In all the answers below (except for the one suggesting I use `span`), the textbox is placed near the top of `#toolbar`. Can it be vertically centered?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. `vertical-align: top`, as per below, with `line-height: 32px` does the trick. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use css-property vertical-align.
Add it to ".other" rule and it's gonna be ok.

```
.other {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    height:32px;
    margin:2px;
}
```

​

Or u can use the advice below, but don't forget to add "overflow: hidden" to #toolbar.

Comment: So simple, but eluded me. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work!  The height of the container is still altered, simply by setting a child's overflow to hidden.  All the content below the container then shifts!  If  you try to hide a child with jQuery.hide, it sets overflow to hidden for the duration of the animation, causing the content below to shift temporarily through the animation.  Setting vertical-align to top on all the child elements does not help; container still changes size.

Comment: @Triynko, i believe you have a different case. V-A is not a silver bullet to use every time. Please, create a separate question or send jsfiddle link in comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them (.button and .other) should have float:left, so everything will be ok

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/q4uNj/14/

Correct css

```
#toolbar {
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
   clear:both;
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 36px;
  margin: 2px;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.other {
    float:left;
    height:32px;
    margin:2px;
    }
```